# label region in bi-level image with python

Tags: python

I want to tag clusters of neighboring pixels from a 2D binary matrix in python.
Basically, I am trying to find something similar to the idl function label_region
http://star.pst.qub.ac.uk/idl/LABEL_REGION.html
Do you have any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the answer is here http://pythonvision.org/basic-tutorial
I used the function `ndimage.label`